# Script `/boot/grub/grub.cfg.new' contains no commands and will do nothing

Tags: grub2, bootloader, boot-repair, grub-efi

I can't able to update grub settings.
If I gave `sudo update-grub` it gives some error like this

```
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Script `/boot/grub/grub.cfg.new' contains no commands and will do nothing
Syntax errors are detected in generated GRUB config file.
Ensure that there are no errors in /etc/default/grub
and /etc/grub.d/* files or please file a bug report with
/boot/grub/grub.cfg.new file attached.
```

I opened `/boot/grub/grub.cfg.new` file

```
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#
```

It was something like this. I also tried reinstalling grub.
 But nothing works.

Attachments:

- [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBJX8.png)
- [grub.cfg.new](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oLppPEZVWIxPnzIHGsX0i7Nol1LugUXC/view?usp=sharing)

Anybody, please help me

Comment: Did you "Ensure that there are no errors in /etc/default/grub and /etc/grub.d/*"?

Comment: Usually it tells you in grub.cfg.new which line has the error. Although when I had a missing } in the middle of my 40_custom, it said the error was at the end of the file. You can try a total reinstall of grub to reset to defaults. But any changes you have made will be lost, if not backed up.

Answer (score 0):

The `update-grub` command is now part of the `grub-pc` package post-installation script, so reinstalling or reconfiguring the grub packages does not work because it always gets stuck on the same error, leaving your package formally not installed and potentially breaking other dependencies.

The only solution that worked for me was to `apt download grub-pc` and then manually extract the config files and copy them to my `/etc`.
After that `sudo apt install --reinstall grub-common grub-pc` will start working and put your system back to normal.